# Execution of printf is ambiguous in a recursive main function

Tags: c, recursion, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  static int i = 5;
  if (--i) {
    main();
    printf("%d ", i);
  }
}
```

The output is

```
0 0 0 0
```

I wonder how `printf` is executed in this program .

Comment: Seems pretty obvious. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger and you'll understand. What output did you expect?

Comment: Funny how some homework assignments don't change even after several years. And recursively calling `main`? Ugh... Anyway, note that you keep calling `main` recursively before ever calling `printf` until the deepest call exists with `i` value of 0 (`main` will not return until `i` reaches 0). That happens at each recursive step along the way (the return of main occurs when `i` is 0). Thus you always get 0.

Comment: What possessed you to type 'static' when writing this code?

Answer (score 5):

Well, `i` is static meaning that is shared among **all** calls  to `main`.

You never print anything before `i` gets down to `0` and since `i` is shared to all calls at the point of the print  all calls see the same value: `0`

- `i=5 if(4) main()`

  - `i=4 if(4) main()`

    - `i=3 if(2) main()`

      - ....

        - `i=0` now. All other calls will see this value. Resursions stops
      - `print 0` cause `i` is static
  - `print 0` cause `i` is static
- `print 0` cause `i` is static

To see what I think is what you expect print before the recursive call as follows:

```
int main() {
  static int i = 5;
   if (--i) {
    printf("%d ", i);
    main();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `printf("%d ",i);` above the inner call to `main()`.

You're on thin ice here:

1. An implicit `return 0;` is inserted at the end of `main` if missing.
2. You can call `main` from itself in C; in C++ the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I fail to see how either of your two caveats are relevant here or constitute "thin ice".

Comment: @EOF, well that would make you a good swimmer. I think it's worth cautioning a beginner against "ace" code like this.

Comment: The second point is entirely irrelevant because nowhere in the question is C++ even mentioned. The first point is entirely irrelevant because nowhere in the program is the return value of `main()` used, so even if the function weren't `main()` and thus didn't have the special case, the lack of returned value would not cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF *so even if the function weren't `main()` and thus didn't have the special case, the lack of returned value would not cause undefined behavior.*  I'm not so sure about that in general.  Imagine a `malloc()` implementation that fell off the end of the function without actually returning a valid pointer...

Comment: @AndrewHenle C11 draft standard n1570: *6.9.1 Function definitions 12 If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.* Note that not returning a value from a function declared to return a value is *fine*, provided the nonexistent value is not used by the caller.

Comment: It's not "thin ice" to not obey the rules of a different language !

Comment: @EOF The return value of main is used by the caller. You can observe this by outputting it from the context that invoked the executable

Comment: @M.M Yes, for `main()` the special rule of `main()` is relevant. But if you had another function call itself recursively, and that function, while declared to return a value, did not return a value, and the value of the function call was not used, that would still be *fine*. Since that other function is not `main()`, its value could not be returned to the environment without being used in the program. In other words, the lack of `return 0;` in this implementation of `main()` is no more "thin ice" than in any other implementation of `main()`.

Comment: It's not thin ice because the standard specifically says it's OK to omit it. But it would be UB in C89